# How to deal with the Cochrane Gambit

Tags: opening, gambits, cochrane-gambit

```
 [fen ""]

 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nxf7 ?!
```

I'm pretty sure the Cochrane Gambit isn't correct. However, I find it difficult to defend against, as some "natural" moves don't seem to work. Can you give some advice how to deal with it? Further, I guess it might be a surprise weapon in a blitz game, so have some of you tried it out?

Comment: For those who don't know the following Topalov-Kramnik game in the Cochrane, just a bit of evidence that the gambit is more playable than it might look at first: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1255554

Comment: A bit of interesting history:  Before the World Championship Match in 1972, Fischer asked some of his friends to find the games and books about Cochrane.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Cochrane Gambit` sacrifies his `Knight` for a few things:

1. He sacrifies the `Knight` for 2 `pawns`
2. After `Kxf7`, `Black` loses castling rights and is dangerously in the
   center.
3. `Blacks King-side` is basically destroyed with only the `g and h pawns`
   and it is not easy to find the best square for the `Black King`. 
   Usually `White` will check with the `Bishop` with `Bf4` and if `Black`
   blocks with `Be3`, then White should just exchange bishops and bring
   the black king further into the center making it harder to castle
   manually.
4. `White` wants to build a strong pawn center by pushing his pawns
   especially on the `king-side`. For example, `White` wants to develop his strong pawn center by pushing `d4`, `f4`, `e5` and further fortify his strength in the center with `Nc3` and `Bd3` or `Bf4`.

With the above said, I think `Black's` goal should be to neutralize `White's` strong pawn center. In the `Kramnik-Topalov` game, I think `Kramnik` made a good move with `5...c5` to challenge the `d4` square. From here White has to chose between playing `6. f4` followed by `7. e5` trying to break `Blacks` position, but in this case `White's` `Bishop` on `c1` is not playing. `Topalov` instead played `6. Bf4+` to not lose any tempo and `6...Be6` is basically forced and after the exchange of `Bishops`, Black's King is more brought deeper into the center.

Some popular replies for `Black` after `5. Nxf7 Kxf7 6. d4` could be:

- c5
- g6
- c6
- Qe8
- Be7

Lets look at the `c5` first:

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nxf7 Kxf7 5. d4 c5
```

`White's` most popular reply is `6. dxc5`, followed by `6...Qa5+ 7. Nc3 Qxc5 8. Be3` and `White` maintains his the initiative.

Now onto `c6`:

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nxf7 Kxf7 5. d4 Be7 6. Nc3 c6
```

Usually with `5...Be7`, Black wants to try to castle manually and `White` continues development with `6. Nc3`. After `6...Re8`, Black is in trouble after `Bf4+`, so instead `6...c6` with the plan of playing `d5` later. After `7...d5`, it might continue `8. exd5 cxd5 9. Nxd5 Nxd5 10. Qh5+ Kf8 11. Bxd5 Qe8`. I would say White is better here because his `Black's` King is still weak and he has `3 pawns` for the `Knight`

Regarding `g6`:

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nxf7 Kxf7 5. d4 g6
```

`g6` might be `Black's` most popular reply. After `6. Nc3 Kg7 7. Be2 d5 8. e5 Ne4 9. Nxe4 dxe4 10. O-O Nc6 11. Be3 h5 12. f3 exf3 13. Rxf3 Be6 14. c4`. Even with this, White still has an advantage.

Last, `Qe8`:

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nxf7 Kxf7 5. d4 Qe8
```

Here `Black` threatens `e4`. It usually continues: `6. Nc3 g6 7. Bd3 Kg7 8. O-O Nc6 9. Bd3 Nc6 10. Be3 Nb4`. `White` may panic here because of the attack on the `White-Squared Bishop`, but instead of panicking, `White` should play `11. h3 Nxd3 12. Qxd3 Rg8`. `Black` wants to play `Kh8`, so `White` should go for the attack with `e5`. `Black` is very disorganized and in a positional disadvantage.

In a nutshell, I believe breaking `White's` center as `Kramnik` did is the best possible way to either draw or defeat the `Cochrane Gambit`

Comment: Edward Dean, Do not touch my post, I did not take any of the above information from Boris Alterman.  You are just out to get me alone.  It doesn't take a genius to figure out c5 tries to break the pawn center, so if Alterman says that and I say it, I must have taken it from him.  You are taking your moderator privileges too far.  It is ridiculous that you just accuse me of not giving credit.  I should give credit to myself as I will mention it again.  The above material was not taken from Alterman.  He is not the authoritative figure on the Cochrane Gambit.

Comment: You are just guessing that I took it from Alterman because he said something about bringing the king into the center and I said the same thing, well it is quite obvious that is what is happening. I don't need Alterman to tell me this.

Answer (score 6):

There are really no two ways about it. When white moves `Nxf7` black *must* respond by accepting the sac with `Kxf7`. From there, it is basically going to be a rough road where black tries to get into a strong defense without giving up the material gained from exposing the king to attack. A good approach here can be to try to get the rook over to f8, or to fiancetto on the king side.

Things to avoid include allowing White successive checks, allowing White to control f7 for too long, allowing White to develop a strong attack while ignoring it, any sort of development queen side before the king is safe, trading the knight on f6, and waiting to move your king to safety (through the approach mentioned above).

Answer (score -2):

I play queen to `e7` and after he takes my rook, I take his pawn, check the king, and try to dominate the center with it. I dont know if it's the right way to play, but that what I would do.

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3.Nxe5 d6 4.Nxf7 Qe7 5.Nxh8 Qxe4
```

Comment: I could not follow your line, on what move do you play `Qe7`?

Comment: @Akavall after Nxf7 i play Qe7, the kight takes my rook, i take the pawn, check, he defends by bringing his bishop or knight to f2,  i work to control the center... i dont know how to insert diagrams otherwise i would have showed you

Comment: I edited your post, is that what you have in mind? You can click `edit` on your post to see the syntax used for diagrams.

Comment: If I understood your above line correctly, white can play `6.Qe2` forcing the exchange of queens and black is just down material.

Comment: @Akavall thanks man i always make that mistake, when you look at it as white or black :D

Comment: This line loses material :( After Qe2 black is down material with nothing gained. Unfortunately with most sacs you have to just grit your teeth and step into the positional mess that you gain when taking the sacced material.

Comment: @TravisJ i know but after `Nxf7` you have to save the queen somehow, either the rook or the queeen are going to be lost

Comment: @Fischer - That is when you take the knight with your king thus saving them both and moving up slightly in material :) - notice that there is nothing stopping your king from taking the knight on f7.

Comment: @TravisJ i think your answer is better than mine and should be the accepted answer, if the king takes, white loses a knight and black dominates the center of the board with his knights, but black won't be able to castle anymore, so he should be careful... if i was white, i'll never play that gambit, it's not a good opening

Comment: How did *anyone* vote this up?

Comment: Answering the Cochrane Gambit with Qe7 is TERRIBLE. After Qxe4, white plays Qe2 and goodbye "dominating the center." In fact that line is so ridiculous white could even liberate his knight with little creativity.